# Java memory model and local variable

Tags: java, java-memory-model

This question is related to java memory model.

I have a java method:

```
public class DataUtil{
  public void process(){
    int c=0;
    c=c+1;

    System.out.println(c);
  }
}
```

In the line "System.out.println(c)", where does the println method takes the value of c variable and prints it on screen?
CPU cache, or RAM

Comment: It very much depends on the case, on the JVM implementation, and on the particular time of the runtime of the application. It may be JIT and it may be a bytecode.. this question is not really narrow and specific.

Comment: Also note that "Java memory model"  is actually a specification that deals mostly with how multi-threaded programs interact with memory and doesn't exactly describe what you're asking for in this question (yes, it's a bit confusing, because conceptually what you are asking about can validly be described as "the Java memory model", but that phrase is already used to mean something slightly different).

Comment: Are you really asking about the Java Memory Model (JMM) here?  Chapter 17.4 of the JLS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be clear, the question and this answer are solely about the behavior of a program with one thread.  Many of the things I say below may not apply to multi-threaded programs.

> Where does the `println` method takes the value of `c` variable and prints it on screen? CPU cache, or RAM

The Java Memory Model (JLS 17.4) **says nothing** definite about cache and RAM.  In general, it specifies visibility behavior without prescribing the way that a particular compiler implements that behavior.  The JMM mandates that there is a *happens before* relation when a thread writes a variable and subsequently reads is.  The happens before constrains the generated code to behave in a certain way.  However it does not mandate any particular implementation approach for achieving those constrains.

In your example, the JMM doesn't even place an implicit constraint on whether the value comes from cache or RAM.  The `c` variable is only accessible to one thread.  (It is a local variable!).  So the compiler could (in theory) store the variable's value anywhere<sup>1</sup>.  The only constraint is that the most recent value is used when the variable is accessed.  The compiler just needs to keep track of where the most recent variable is kept ...

As a general rule, the JMM only has something interesting to say about variables and objects that are shared by *different* threads.

---

<sup>1 - In a register, in RAM, in cache memory, on a hardware stack ... even written on a piece of paper shoved down the back of the sofa, if your hardware platform supports that.</sup>

---

If you are using "memory model" in a broader sense, then the plain answer is "we cannot say".

- In languages (not Java!) where the memory model is specified in terms of main memory and cache, the memory model would *most likely* not constrain this example.
- If you are not talking about any specific memory model, but just asking if the value is fetched from cache or RAM, then we cannot say ... because this is an *implementation detail* of the language implementation.  For example, the JVM.

What we *can say* with a high level of certainty<sup>2</sup> is that the implementation will fetch and print the most recent value of `c` from *somewhere* in this example.

In the case of Java, the JLS says that it *must* return the most recent value.  (It's in JLS 17.4 if you want to look.)  The JLS leaves it up to the Java implementation to decide how to do that.

It is safe to assume that any JVM implementation will have come up with a reliable solution; i.e. that the most recent value of a variable will be used.  But figuring out the details would be a big task ... and (IMO) would not worth the effort.  (You don't need to understand the internals of a Volvo 264 automatic gearbox to drive a car.)

---

<sup>2 - We can be certain because there aren't bazillions of bug reports of single threaded application not working due to problems reading and writing variables.  Also, if there are any doubts, it is possible to examine the JIT compiler source code to understand what it does, or analyze the native code that it generates.</sup>

Comment: The println method should constantly take the variable value from RAM, never from the cpu cache.

Comment: Sorry, but that is simply false.  You won't find anything in the Java Language Specification to support that.  It is the JLS which determines how a Java program *should* behave.

Comment: The only case where the JLS (effectively) requires the latest RAM value to be used is for a `volatile` field.

Answer (score 1):

The Java Memory Model does not regulate that - it's focused on behaviours of multi-threaded programs.
Local variables are allocated on *stack*. Parameters to functions, such as `println`, are also passed via stack - they are pushed onto the top of the stack before the call (according to the *calling convention*). It's what happens in bytecode, though JIT compilers or the interpreter may also use CPU registers, and do not use the stack in the RAM.

Comment: It should be added that conceptually the stack is a part of the RAM, but various optimizations might actually mean that variables on the stack don't end up anywhere in main memory (for example if a CPU register is used instead for the entire life-time of a local variable).

Comment: While this is true it is not related to question asked.

Comment: @eis The question asked was " where does the println method takes the value of c variable and prints it on screen? CPU cache, or RAM". I'll add the part that JMM does not regulate it, though.

Comment: I'd agree with eis. I have a similar comment on another question. This answer is more elaborating on a so called Heap and Stack representations; while question is about lowest level physical storage.

Comment: @GiorgiTsiklauri - Incorrect.  This question is about the Java memory model.  And the JMM is **not** about physical storage at all.  At least, not directly.  It is actually about visibility of changes to shared variables ... independent of the physical storage.

Comment: @StephenC I'm not sure that you are correct; yes, question is **titled** so, but did you pay attention to the payload of the question, itself? it clearly asks "*In the line "System.out.println(c)", where does the println method takes the value of c variable and prints it on screen? CPU cache, or RAM*" CPU cache or RAM is exactly the physical level of the storage. That's why I initially commented, that OP seems to have a bit of ambiguity in *what* really is a question.

Comment: It is unambiguous to me.  The OP is asking about what the Java Memory Model says about this.  Now, it is pretty clear that the OP doesn't know what the JMM really is.  However, the question as written is clear.

Comment: @StephenC why you just so determinedly ignore the text of the question itself? well, it's just because of you like to read it so? :) enjoy the interpretation then.

Comment: I am not ignoring it. I am taking the title and the body **together**; i.e. "What does the JMM say about whether the c is read from cache or RAM".  And I am also taking account of the first sentence of the Question which reads: *"This is about the java memory model"*.

Comment: ..and what does your answer have to do with this particular answer? ok, doesn't matter.

Comment: I'm not commenting on this Answer.  I am commenting on your comment.  (Pay attention :-) )   And I should note that Andrew's comment and action indicates that he at least understood the significance of the JMM in the question that was asked.

Comment: @StephenC note that those were additions added after our comments. I think the confusion is just that OP thinks this is related to JMM, while it is a specific concept that is not related to his question.

Comment: also, line "It's what happens in bytecode, though JIT compilers or the interpreter may also use CPU registers, and do not use the stack in the RAM." in this answer just isn't strictly correct or making a lot of sense, either. I did upvote Stephen C's answer as I think that one is answering to the question.

Comment: @eis Could you, please, elaborate on what's wrong with this line?

Comment: @AndrewVershinin first of all, there is no "the interpreter" in this context. some JVMs might have an interpreter for byte code but most will compile to native code. "do not use use the stack in the RAM" is not generally correct as there probably isn't a JVM that wouldn't use stack in the RAM at all. stack also happens in the jvm, not in the bytecode. and compiler doesn't decide if ram or cpu is used, jvm does. it's just full of misleading information.

Comment: @eis By "the interpreter" I meant the interpreter of HotSpot, the reference implementation of JVM, and every Java program starts in the interpreter, before it's compiled into native code. I didn't say anywhere that the stack/RAM is not used at all - I've just mentioned that this could be the case after it's compiled by JIT. By "stack happens in the bytecode" I meant that the bytecode will contain (typed) `push`/`pop` instructions used to pass parameters. "compiler doesn't decide if ram or cpu is used, jvm does" - JIT compilers are part of JVM, it's not a contradiction.